# Set Pagestyle for new chapter types

Tags: header-footer, chapters, koma-script

I have created my own chapter command *sheet* and want to use it in the same document as a normal chapter. Both should have separate pagestyles. For the first pages of the both chapter types I found a solution. But is there a way to change the pagestyle for the rest of the sheet?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\RequirePackage{pageslts}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
level=0,
font=\usekomafont{chapter},
tocindent=0em,
tocnumwidth=5.75em,
style=chapter,%
tocstyle=chapter%
]{sheet}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{sheet}{%
    \chead*{\currentpagestyle}
    \ofoot*{\pagemark/\lastpageref{LastPage}}
}

\chead*{\currentpagestyle}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{chapter}{%
    \chead*{\currentpagestyle}
    \ofoot*{\pagemark}
}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\sheetpagestyle}{sheet}
\pagestyle{chapter}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \lipsum[1-10]
    \sheet{Sheet 1}
    \lipsum[1-10]
    \chapter{Chapter 2} 
    \lipsum[1-10]
    \sheet{Sheet 2}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

I know the pagenumbering seems to make no sense in this example. I just wanted to have a little difference to keep the example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

KOMA-Script classes `scrbook` and `scrreprt` provide commands and options only for the first page of a heading with `style=chapter` or `style=part`. AFAIK there is no simple command or option to change the page style of the following pages.

But you could patch `\chapter` and `\sheet` and maybe `\part` to change the page style of following pages:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\part{\clearpage\pagestyle{scrheadings}}{}{}
\xpretocmd\chapter{\clearpage\pagestyle{chapter}}{}{}
\xpretocmd\sheet{\clearpage\pagestyle{sheet}}{}{}
```

The `\clearpage` ensures that the page style is not changed on the last page of the previous chapter or sheet.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\DeclareNewSectionCommand[%
  level=\chapternumdepth,
  font=\usekomafont{chapter},
  tocindent=0em,
  tocnumwidth=5.75em,
  style=chapter,%
  tocstyle=chapter,%
  pagestyle=sheet% <- added
]{sheet}

\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{chapter}

\chead*{\currentpagestyle}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{sheet}{%
  \ofoot*{\pagemark/\lastpageref{LastPage}}
}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{chapter}{%
  \ofoot*{\pagemark}
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\part{\clearpage\pagestyle{scrheadings}}{}{}
\xpretocmd\chapter{\clearpage\pagestyle{chapter}}{}{}
\xpretocmd\sheet{\clearpage\pagestyle{sheet}}{}{}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Chapter 1}
  \lipsum[1-10]
  \sheet{Sheet 1}
  \lipsum[1-10]
  \chapter{Chapter 2} 
  \lipsum[1-10]
  \sheet{Sheet 2}
  \lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]