# How to customise page numbering?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am currently writing my honours thesis.

The following is a MWE of what I have:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2.54 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{headings}

\section{Motivation}

Blah blah blah.

\newpage

More blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```

Currently, all of my page numbers appear at the top-right of each page.

However, the guidelines from my university on page numbers are as follows:

"The page number for the first page of each chapter, as well as preliminaries, should appear at the bottom of the page. For the rest of the pages, the page number should appear at the top-right hand corner (2 cm from the top, 2.5 cm from the right)."

Thus, I would like the page number with the page starting the section "Motivation" to appear at the bottom-center of the page. Of course, this should hold for the start of all other sections too but for all other pages, they should adopt the "headings" page style. In particular, if Page 1 is the page with "blah blah blah", then that page number should be at the bottom of the page and centered. If Page 2 is the page with "More blah blah blah", then that page number should be at the top-right of the page.

How can I do this? For example, is there a pre-set style that I can use already?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try `\pagestyle{headings}` in your preamble and switch to `report` instead of `article` because only then you will be able to have chapters.

Comment: Alternatively you can define your own header and footer using `fancyhdr` package.

Comment: @Οὖτις no I mean having chapters is not the point here. Assuming sections is the top, I’m just wondering how I can set the page number for the start of each section to be at the bottom of the page. Or do you mean to say that, if I actually did have chapters, then this can actually be done with the report document class?

Comment: what I mean is that `\documentclass[11 pt]{report}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Motivation}
Blah.
\newpage
More blah.
\end{document}` gives (despite the spacing) what is described in your guidelines. Probably it is possible to do this also for sections, but I don't know that right away. Maybe you want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444269/237192.

Comment: @Οὖτις thank you! I think that’s actually what my university wants. Would you be able to write this as an answer so that I may accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily if you are willing to change your documentclass to `report`. This will also enable you to use `\chapter`s as the highest level, which seems to be intended by your university:

> The page number for the first page of each **chapter**, as well as preliminaries, should appear at the bottom of the page. For the rest of the pages, the page number should appear at the top-right hand corner (2 cm from the top, 2.5 cm from the right).

You will achieve the wanted behavior using `\pagestyle{headings}` in your preamble: Pages which start a new chapter will use the `plain` pagestyle (page number in footer), the others will use `headings` (page number in header). It is possible to further customize them. If you need more options, maybe `fancyhdr` package will come in handy.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Motivation}
Blah.
\newpage
More blah.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]